# Scenarios from K number of designs in N number of positions - Python

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, combinatorics

I am trying to generate all the possible scenarios which I can place `k` number of designs in `n` number of positions. Which should give k^n scenarios. For example lets say `k = 2` and `n = 3`, all the scenarios are:

| n1 | n2 | n3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

so there has to be 8 (2^8) scenarios.

I have tried `combinations` , `permutations` and `combinations_with_replacement` from `itertools` but none of seem to give the solution which I am trying for.

Is there a `python` function to generate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a product:

```
for p in itertools.product(range(1,3),repeat = 3):
    print(p)

(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Oh yes, something more than `product`. Brilliant, thank you very much. Really appreciate this Sir :)